# How long does it take to mine a piece of cobblestone with a diamond pickaxe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When constantly mining a cobblestone ore with a diamond pickaxe, how long does it take per block to break?

Comment: Hi idrek, welcome to Arqade. Typically we encourage questions that show research effort, which this one does not appear to have. I anticipate this is why the question has been downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

As seen in the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breaking#Blocks_by_hardness), a diamond pickaxe (without the efficiency enchantment) takes 0.4 seconds to break each block of cobblestone.